# Put two UIViewControllers on screen side by side

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uikit

On iPad, I've got a main UIViewController that's supposed to embed side by side two childViewControllers. How can I instantiate them both, and put them on screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use container views in IB. Drag out 2 container views into the controllers view, and size them how you want. You will automatically get two connected view controllers, sized appropriately. The main view controller, and its two children will all be instantiated at the same time. If you need to get access to the children from the parent, you use self.childViewControllers.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew about IB's containers view. What if I want to do this in code?

Comment: @grasGendarme, then you need to read up on custom container controllers, and use the api that's in the "Managing Child View Controllers in a Custom Container" section of the UIViewController CLass Reference

Comment: I've read it but it lacks explanation on how to handle the positions of the child VCs

Comment: @grasGendarme, In code, you can just set the frame of the added views, as you would for any subview. If you're using auto layout, that should be done with constraints, if not, then just use setFrame:

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should use a [UISplitViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) as a container for two view controllers:

> The UISplitViewController class is a container view controller that
>   manages the presentation of two side-by-side view controllers.